# What is the meaning of this code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, conditional-statements

```
if (exist.IndexOf("true") == -1)
{
    //first condition

}
else
{
    // second condition
}
```

What is the meaning of it if I use `(exist.IndexOf("true") != -1)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see in MSDN, "**[String.IndexOf Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx)**".

Answer (score 13):

Well, typically `IndexOf` returns -1 if the item couldn't be found. So, first condition will execute if the string "true" isn't present in `exist`.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively,

```
if (!exist.Contains("true"))
{
  //first condition
}
else
{
  // second condition
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code tests if the string held in the variable `exist` contains the substring "true", and if it does, it executes the "2nd condition" block, otherwise it executes the "1st condition" block.

Answer (score 1):

do first condition, when the text "true" is not found in string `exist`, or do second condition if found. `.IndexOf` return the position of string if found, and return -1 if not found.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `exist` holds a string. Being that correct, [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) returns the index of the first occurrence of a substring (in this case, `true`). If `-1` is returned, then the substring wasn't found.